# Best plotting software with latex integration

Tags: plot, matlab, software

I'm wondering if there is a software that can create plots with latex integration like gnuplot. 
I have used gnuplot to create very nice 2D plots with epslatex terminal and I find it superb, but unfortunately gnuplot doesn't have ternary plot option.
OriginPro doesn't have latex integration option, so I exclude it from my list.
I want a plotting software that can handle anything with publication quality graphs, because I'm doing my undergraduate thesis, preferable on Linux platform. 
What about Mathematica, MATLAB, or something else, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

PS Sorry if I posted in wrong section.

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229959/15036 ?

Comment: What is a ternary plot?  3D?

Comment: @JimHefferon, no, a ternary plot is e.g. <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192043>.

Comment: @NikosK., I personally like [`pgfplots`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), but also `tikz` as a very good [Data Visualization](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=756) library.

Comment: About the LaTeX integration in OriginPro: Googling "Origin LaTeX" gave the the result http://originlab.de/fileExchange/details.aspx?fid=221. Is that an option? (I don't know Origin.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow, I don't know how to use pgfplots or tiks. I will search though.
Thanks

Comment: The idea with these LaTeX packages is, that you can *calculate* your plots in whatever software you like and export the (data) points to a file which than can be read by the packages to create the plot. In special cases, where the plot itself, i.e. without the axis and annotations, cannot be "made" with the packages, you can export that plot and then import it into an axis environment of the packages to again have all fonts etc. used by LaTeX/the packages. ...

Comment: ... Only axis types that are not supported by the packages need to be done by external programs like 3D ternary plots, multiple discontinued axis, ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow, Thanks my friend, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica has a package that provides LaTeX integration:

- [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX)

Here's a screenshot of a plot from the section of the documentation which discusses matching styles:

[image]

Here's a question from Mathematica.SE about creating ternary plots:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39733/how-to-plot-ternary-density-plots

Disclosure: I am the author of MaTeX.

Comment: So If I understood it right, with MaTex I can have Latex typesetting in Mathematica. Then I can export my graphs and include it in my LaTeX document. If I have the same font in Mathematica and LaTeX, the same size, etc, etc then the graph I made in Mathematica would be "like" I did it in LaTeX itself. Am I right?
Thanks for posting though my friend!

Comment: @NikosK. MaTeX just makes it easy to use LaTeX to typeset formulas within Mathematica. The typical use case is figure labels.  You don't need MaTeX to export figures for use with LaTeX.  The aim of MaTeX is not to be able to use Computer Modern as the font in Mathematica (although it *can* be used for that). You can have "LaTeX fonts" by installing [Latin Modern fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) for your OS. *The primary goal of MaTeX is to give you LaTeX's high-quality math typesetting directly within Mathematica.* I was unsatisfied with Mathematica's typesetting.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the main purpose of the package!
I want to work with mathematica and learn as much as I can for its plotting capabilities. So that will help in order to have nice graphs!

Answer (score 4):

Nico Schlömer has created packages to generate `pgfplots` code from both Matlab and `matplotlib` plots. I don't know if they handle ternary plots though.

- [`matlab2tikz` on FileExchange](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) (See [GitHub](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz) for issue tracker etc.)
- [`matplotlib2tikz` on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib2tikz) (See [GitHub](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz/wiki) for issue tracker etc.)

`matplotlib` also has a `pgf` backend (see e.g. http://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html#pgf-tutorial) that will generate low-level (and rather unflexible) `pgf` code from basically what ever type of plot `matplotlib` can make.

For a comparison between `matplotlib2tikz` and the `pgf` backend, see [Matplotlib's PGF vs Matplotlib2Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196368/matplotlibs-pgf-vs-matplotlib2tikz).

Answer (score 0):

While matlab is really good, I so far have had the best luck with root from cern. After plotting the data a tex file can be saved directly from the graph, if needed editing font can also be done in the tex file; note it is not an uneditable svg file. The disadvantage is it is very low level programming and it doesn't have a very large support community. It is free software and you can visit the website at https://root.cern.ch/